# Recursive CTE to return all connected Nodes in Path

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a table that creates a path by linking two "nodes" together.

```
Node
-----------
Id - Primary Key
Name 
etc...


Path
------
Id - Primary Key
From - FK to Node
To - FK to Node
```

So this path:

```
W --- X --- Y --- Z
```

can be built like this:

```
Node
Id   Name
---  -----
1    W
2    X
3    Y
4    Z
5    A
6    B
7    C


Path
Id  From     To
--- -------  -------
1   1        2
2   2        3
3   3        4
4   6        7
```

I have come up with a recursive CTE query that given any Node Id, traverses the paths and returns all "Paths" involved.

```
declare @nodeId = 2
;WITH cte AS (

    -- ANCHOR
    -- Find one path involving Node
    SELECT top 1 p.*, 0 as [Seq] FROM dbo.Path p WHERE [From] = @nodeId or [To] = @nodeId 

    union all

    -- go left
    select leftPath.*, cte.[Seq] - 1 as [Seq]
    from [Path] leftPath
    join cte on cte.[From] = leftPath.[To] and cte.[Seq] <= 0

    union all

    -- go right
    select rightPath.*, cte.[Seq] + 1 as [Seq]
    from [Path] rightPath
    join cte on cte.[To] = rightPath.[From] and cte.[Seq] >= 0
)

SELECT cte.Id, cte.Seq, cte.From, cte.To
FROM cte 
order by [Seq]
```

So this returns all paths -

```
Path
Id  Seq From     To
--- --- -------  -------
1   -1   1        2
2   0    2        3
3   1    3        4
```

But how can I write a query that given one of the Node Ids, traverses the path to the left and right and returns ALL DISTINCT (ordered) nodes involved?

```
    Id   Name
    ---  -----
    1    W
    2    X
    3    Y
    4    Z
```

Comment: Your query doesnt seem to work, for example `description` doesnt exist. Please fix this and I will take a look http://rextester.com/DEVHNG47817

Comment: Fixed; see: http://rextester.com/live/QBDQ1655

Comment: That query doesnt match your output. Not negative `Seq`

Comment: There is an issue, you share a `LIVE` code so when I edit change the code. use the bottom `FORK`  to create a separated version.

Comment: try this? http://rextester.com/edit/DEVHNG47817  Seq doesn't really matter, it was probly different due to how the TOP 1 is picking up the default order, I put an order by clause in there just to match the example for you.  All it does is order the results correctly

Comment: what is the result you are expecting exactly? You want to filter by node id 2 and the result contains all? Only contains node id 2 in from or to? Paint the complet result please. Sorry for my english, new mobile keyboard.

Comment: @JavierJimenezMatilla see my last paragraph in my question. I want the rows from table Node, in the order they are connected: W -- X -- Y -- Z - ALL DISTINCT (ordered) nodes involved. I know I can massage the data into this format, I was just hoping for a slight modification to my query or a similar query to make this happen.

Comment: Sorry again I don't understand w-- y... I think you don't need a cte for this question only right JOIN and LEFT JOIN with the same table but I need to see the completo result, to understand. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What I'm saying is this:

```
DECLARE @nodeId int = 2;   

select 
*
from Node t1
inner join Path t2
on t1.Id = t2.[From] or t1.Id = t2.[To]
where t1.Id = @nodeId
order by t1.Id
```

I know, the above query doesn't resolve your question but, with this query you have got the same result than with the cte and is more simple.  From this query What is the result you are expecting, if the query doesn't do yet.

But I understand that is not what you want. For that I need a complet example of the result that you want, the last paragraph I read is the table node. ¿?

Comment: You are right a more complex sample should otherwise `select * From Node order by id` return the desire output too.

Comment: updated question. added 3 new nodes, and one new path. so now there are 2 paths - W-X-Y-Z, and B-C.  Running my original query width nodeid 2 produces the same results as before - the entire path nodeid 2 (named X) is involved in. My query returns the edges of the graph, I want it to return the vertices.

Answer (score 0):

This returns the result your want, but for the case of `@nodeId int = 5;` it doesn't return anything because there is no path associated with that node.

See I get the `Name's` from the `cte.[From]` and then add another `Name` from the ***last*** id `cte.[To]`

I add a source, to make sure the order is the one you show in the output. otherwise because the last two `Name's` belong to the same row could have inverted order.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/FGSC92828)**

```
;WITH cte AS (

    -- ANCHOR
    -- Find one path involving Node
    SELECT top 1 p.*, 0 as [Seq] FROM dbo.Path p WHERE [From] = @nodeId or [To] = @nodeId order by [From] desc

    union all

    -- go left
    select leftPath.*, cte.[Seq] - 1 as [Seq]
    from [Path] leftPath
    join cte on cte.[From] = leftPath.[To] and cte.[Seq] <= 0

    union all

    -- go right
    select rightPath.*, cte.[Seq] + 1 as [Seq]
    from [Path] rightPath
    join cte on cte.[To] = rightPath.[From] and cte.[Seq] >= 0
)

SELECT 'A' as [Source], cte.Id, cte.Seq, cte.[From], cte.[To], Node.[Name]
FROM cte 
JOIN Node
  ON cte.[From] = Node.[Id]
UNION  
SELECT 'B' as [Source], cte.Id, cte.Seq, cte.[From], cte.[To], Node.[Name]
FROM cte 
JOIN Node
  ON cte.[To] = Node.[Id]  
WHERE cte.id = (SELECT Max(Id) FROM cte)  

order by [Source], [Seq]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
@nodeId int = 1 to 4 same result:
```

[image]

```
@nodeId int = 6 to 7 same result:
```

[image]

If you put the previous query also in CTE and called `step2` you can have your desire format like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Source], [Seq]) as [Id],
       Name
FROM step2
```

**Final Output**

[image]